# Is it Possible to Integrate AWS EC2 Image Builder with CI/CD tools like Jenkins, Semaphore ad Build Golde Images from that.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration

Hi I have tried to build Golden Image from Locally/API by adding my Service/Packages.
But, Is it possible to Integrate with CI/CD tools like webhook. Whenever pushes happen needs to build the golden Image using **EC2 Image Builder**.

Comment: Depends how you define "integrate". But in general terms it can work with anything which executes aws api. If you can run aws cli on jenkins or codebuild you can manage EC2 image builder using its [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/imagebuilder/index.html) or aws lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Marcin said, it all depends what do you mean by "integrate". AFAIK you can use AWS EC2 with most of them. Personally I'm using buddy.works and I'm using AWS EC2 there.

You can check their documentation: [https://buddy.works/docs/deployments/aws/ec2](https://buddy.works/docs/deployments/aws/ec2?utm_source=sof&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=falcz)

Let me know if that's what you've been looking for.